Blackboard framing for embedded surfaces
A framed link is a link $L\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ equiped with the data of a normal vector field, called the framing; an isotopy of a framed link is an ambient isotopy, altering the framing accordingly. We say that a framing is a blackboard framing if it sits in a plane of $\mathbb{R}^3$. (Equivalently, a blackboard framing is a framing inherited from a diagram of the link, equiped with the trivial framing of the plane of projection.)

fact: every framed link is isotopic to a blackboard framed link.

Now consider the analogue question for an embedded surface; more precisely, a link cobordism $\Sigma\colon L_0\to L_1$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3\times[0,1]$, such that $\partial\Sigma=L_0\cup L_1$ and $L_i=\Sigma\cap(\mathbb{R}^3\times\{i\})$. A (surface) framing for $\Sigma$ is the data of a normal vector field, and a blackboard framing is a framing sitting in $\mathbb{R}^2\times[0,1]$, for some plane $\mathbb{R}^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$.

question: is every framed embedded surface isotopic to a blackboard framed embedded surface?


I elaborate on the question. The framing of a framed link can be pictured on a link diagram, using colours to depict the missing dimension:

The framing above is not a blackboard framing for the plane of projection, but this can be fixed by perfoming an isotopy to the link, which comes down to a Reidemeister I move on the diagram.
Similarly, a diagram for an embedded surface is a choice of projection onto $\mathbb{R}^2\times[0,1]$, and one can again picture the framing with colours. Rotating the above 1d case around the center gives a framing for an open disk. Seen from the top, the color scheme looks like this:

The projection of the framing is zero along the black circle.
As a weaker version of the question, one can ask whether this framed embedded disk can be isotoped into a blackboard framed disk.

I think your "fact" is wrong.  For the trivial knot the only framing that is isotopic to a blackboard framing is the one with linking number zero.

I meant up to performing an isotopy to the link (I corrected the question accordingly). In your example, I allow one to isotope the trivial embedding of the unknot into one with an arbitrary number of kinks ("Reidemeister I").

I also find your def a bit confusing. To me, "blackboard framing" refers to a framing inherited from the tautological framing of the plane by looking at a diagram for your link on that plane, and then indeed every framing is obtained this way, exactly as you say, by  applying RI's to your diagrams. Is this what you have in mind ?

Yes indeed, that's what I had in mind. I just thought that stating it without any reference to a diagram made the question clearer.

I added some clarifications to the question

I think the answer to your question is yes.  Framings for a surface in $R^4$ are roughly elements of $H^1(\Sigma)$.  So the idea would be to take the dual curves to your $H^1$ element and locally modify the embedding around those dual curves.  The modification I have in mind is much like a $S^1$-parametric Reidemeister 1 move.  There's probably a cleaner argument than this, but something like this appears to work.

how is a framing roughly an element of $H^1(\Sigma)$?

The normal bundle is trivial, so once you fix that trivialization, a framing is a map $\Sigma \to S^1$, which (up to homotopy) is an element of $H^1 \Sigma$. In general there is a theorem of this sort called Brown Representability. For standard singular cohomology it states $\pi_0 Maps(X, K(G,n)) \simeq H^n(X, G)$. So we use that the circle is a (ℤ,1)

space.


Thank you, this clarifies. Although I don't think I understand the rest of the argument, I assume that when you say "$S^1$-parametric Reidemeister move", you are thinking about a situation similar to the one I describe in the addendum to the question. It is not so clear to mean me that "rotating Reidemeister I" would give a valid framed embedded surface diagram, presenting the same framed embedded surface as the original framed surface diagram.

Your black circles where the framing is "out of page" would have to be homologically non-trivial circles in the surface.  You get them from the element of $H^1$, i.e. if you view it as a map $\Sigma \to S^1$ you take the pre-image of a point, that gives you a collection of disjoint circles where you perform the "parametric Reidemeister move" to the framing.
